# Keras Error: Data cardinality is ambiguous

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying the following snippet on 64 images of size 28,28,1, but it throws

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous
```

despite I think the dimensions of the tensors being correct.

```
loss = model_net.train_on_batch(Batch_X, Batch_Y)
print(type(Batch_X)):<class 'list'>
print(type(Batch_X[1][0])):<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(type(Batch_Y)):<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(np.shape(Batch_X)):(2, 64, 28, 28, 1)
print(np.shape(Batch_Y)):(64,)
```

Model is

```
input_shape=(28,28,1)
left_input = Input(input_shape)
right_input = Input(input_shape)

model = Sequential([
Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'),
MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2),
Flatten(),
Dense(units=4096, activation='sigmoid')])
model.summary()


encoded_l = model(left_input)
encoded_r = model(right_input)

subtracted = keras.layers.Subtract()([encoded_l, encoded_r])
prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(subtracted) 
model_net = Model(inputs=[left_input, right_input], outputs=prediction)    
optimizer= Adam(learning_rate=0.0006)
model_net.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
plot_model(model_net, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

In the above you can see the model takes in 2 images simultaneously for forward pass; thus every element in Batch_X comprises of 2 matrixes. Any suggestions where I am likely making a mistake.

Comment: Without seeing details of `model_net` it will be hard to understand the error.

Comment: The dimensions are not correct, the first element of the shape of X and Y has to be the same, and from your question we can see it is not.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply. I have added better description of the model in the question now. I hope this clarifies